# Why have my items moved vertical when I copy the html into wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I made a local test page to layout images and content and get things right. However, when I move the code over to my wordpress site, the rows of images are now columns. I've made unique class and id names so it's not an existing css.
What should I be looking for?

This is my code that works locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="intro">
      This is the intro text
    </div>
    <div class="topRow">
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">Header 1</div>
          <div class="modal-body">Body 1</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">Footer 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4></div>
          <div class="modal-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut nisl egestas, pharetra eros nec, feugiat est. Vivamus lobortis mauris libero, sit amet consectetur nisl ultrices quis. Nullam eu dolor sed est elementum dictum sed eget nibh. Sed mauris eros, tincidunt eget orci non, euismod commodo metus. Nullam cursus at justo et viverra. Vestibulum id diam placerat, ultrices lorem nec, suscipit libero. Nulla condimentum urna at lectus vestibulum, a ullamcorper urna consectetur. Donec maximus, ex non lobortis sagittis, dui lorem consequat velit, nec euismod tortor tortor ac velit. In eu dignissim tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis auctor ex lacus, nec posuere dui accumsan eget.</p><p>Quisque sollicitudin quis ex ac ullamcorper. Vivamus ipsum mi, scelerisque vitae risus a, varius mollis tellus. Sed in massa vehicula, molestie tellus a, ornare urna. In volutpat velit vel neque commodo, et pellentesque ipsum rutrum. Phasellus felis arcu, fringilla ac feugiat sit amet, sollicitudin sed dui. Duis eget vestibulum mi, quis elementum mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas aliquam lacinia nisl, a malesuada orci sollicitudin nec. Nullam vitae pharetra turpis, id eleifend risus. Nulla id placerat augue, ac efficitur justo.</p><p>Duis semper dui vel est commodo tristique. Ut hendrerit imperdiet mattis. Vestibulum feugiat vulputate mollis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque placerat eros a vestibulum laoreet. Vestibulum at enim vulputate, cursus ex sit amet, suscipit metus. Morbi hendrerit non lacus nec imperdiet. Donec sit amet odio sit amet ligula rhoncus laoreet non eget tortor. In et nunc diam. Ut a ipsum ullamcorper, luctus turpis id, congue massa. Sed sit amet vulputate purus. Phasellus ac vulputate tortor. Quisque vitae ultrices odio.</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="tableRow">
      <button type="button" class="Category">Category 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/101/101/);"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="tableRow">
      <button class="Category">Category 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/101/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/102/101/);"> </button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottomRow">
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
      <button type="button" class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/)"></button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the css:

```
#wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.square{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
  border: none; 
  border-radius:0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.Category{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px; 
  border: none; 
  border-radius:0px; 
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.topRow{
  margin: 10px 100px 50px 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tableRow{
  margin: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bottomRow{
  margin: 50px 100px 50px 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper span {
   float: left;
   clear: left;
}

.modal-dialog {
   width: 75%;
   height: 70%;
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

On my local machine it looks like the first image. When I port the code to wordpress, it looks like the second.

[image: What I want it to look like; horizontal]
[image: What it looks like on Wordpress]

Comment: please upload some code samples

Comment: Since you have uploaded the working local code, how can we check for the error, provide an example highlighting the error.

Comment: Its impossible to know without knowing the rest of the site setup, but instincts tell me that the css from your WP theme are setting styles for elements that your css is not overriding, e.g. the button element could be styled as `display:block`. I suggest explicitly making your buttons inline  by adding `.square{ display:inline-block;}`

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten. But that still kept them as the second pic... any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your boostrap.min.js is loading? Did you include it into the functions.php file via `wp_enqueue_scripts`? Or maybe check that there is not some typo in it.

Comment: Thanks @Tedds. I've checked and they are definitely loading.

Comment: Npt without seeing how the page works. Is it possible to get a link to a test site?

Comment: I just noticed that the html has <br> inserted between the buttons when it renders. How can I stop that (why does it happen)?

Comment: How are you adding the code to your Wordpress site, e.g. hardcoded in a theme, inserted using PHP, etc? Please include the actual code the has the issue, rather than what worked on your test page that works. Its impossible to debug an issue if we can't see the code that has the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress automatically inserts 
 elements around some tags.
Either a function to stop this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content

or remove the whitespace between elements: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152091/disable-wp-automatically-inserted-line-breaks-after-an-image